# angularjs - push new object(as scope) to my list(in services)

Tags: angularjs, arrays, service, controller, push

How to push new object in my array list where my list is in services?

In my controller I have functions that push new layer of object to my list, but since I moved my list array to new file as service. it wont work anymore.

Controller:

```
$scope.addContact = function () {
        $scope.person.contact.push({
            contactType: "",
            contactNumber: ""
        });            
    };
```

Services:

```
angular
    .module("person")
    .service("InitService", initializeItem);

function initializeItem() {

    var self = this;

    self.ReturnInit = function () {
        var person = {
            firstname: "",
            lastname: "",
            address: [
                {
                    addresstype: "",
                    addresslocation: ""
                }
            ],
            contact: [
                {
                    contacttype: "",
                    contactnumber: ""
                }
            ]
        };

        return person;

    };

};
```

everytime I "addContact" it will ".push" new object to my list.

Looking for this:

```
person = {
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
        address: [
            {
                addresstype: "",
                addresslocation: ""
            },{
                addresstype: "",
                addresslocation: ""
            }
        ],
        contact: [
            {
                contacttype: "",
                contactnumber: ""
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move person var to upper level of your service and then use it like this.

Service:

```
angular
    .module("person")
    .service("InitService", initializeItem);

function initializeItem() {

    var self = this;
    var person = {
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
        address: [{
            addresstype: "",
            addresslocation: ""
        }],
        contact: [{
            contacttype: "",
            contactnumber: ""
        }]
    };

    self.ReturnInit = function() {
        return person;

    };
    self.addContact = function(contact) {
        person.contact.push(contact);
    }
};
```

Controller:

```
$scope.addContact = function() {
    InitService.addContact({
        contactType: "",
        contactNumber: ""
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, `$scope.person` will reference the object returned by `InitService`

```
$scope.person = InitService.ReturnInit();
$scope.addContact = function () {
        $scope.person.contact.push({
            contactType: "",
            contactNumber: ""
        });            
    };
```